# How to force typescript not to use default when partial generic is used with constrain generic

Tags: typescript

I got code like this:

```
const constrainGenericTest = <T extends string, F extends (arg: Parameters<F>) => number = (...args: any) => any>(
  fn: F
): F => {
  return fn;
};
constrainGenericTest<string>((arg: string) => arg)(1);
```

TypeScript doesn't show an error for calling function `constrainGenericTest` result with the wrong type, because always takes the default value of generic `F`. Is it possible to say TypeScript to get type from a function parameter instead of default value without specify second generic like that

`constrainGenericTest<string, (arg: string) => number>((arg: string) => arg)(1);`?